# Ember Data Mapping Issues with Sinatra api

Tags: javascript, ember.js, sinatra

I am very new to ember and am currently working on an (very) lightweight ember application backed by a sinatra api. I am having some issues with mapping the JSON provided by my api into the actual ember objects. Whenever I attempt to render a template using this data I am given "Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key 0 but you have no mapping for it"

This is the JSON format of my API:

```
[{"sha":"c1133d9ec33"},{"sha":"2b2d4dd4590"}.....]
```

My Snippets of my Ember code are below:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  revision: 12,
});

App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('commits', function(){
    this.route('commits', {path: '/:sha'});
  });
});

//COMMITS
App.CommitsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return App.Commit.find(); //pulls all commts at /commits
  }
});

//COMMIT
App.CommitRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return App.Commit.find(params.sha);
  }
});

App.Commit = DS.Model.extend({
  sha: DS.attr('string'),
  image_url: function() {
    return 'http://localhost:9393/commits' + this.get('sha');
  }.property('sha')
});
```

Any insight as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ember Data expects your API to return with named roots.

You need to update your API to return JSON with a root

`{"commits": [{"sha":"c1133d9ec33"},{"sha":"2b2d4dd4590"}.....]}`